# Angular calculate column of remaining Rest Api

Tags: arrays, angular

There is an Array which looks like this

```
Array [{ first:"main",subcategory : [{ first: "sub",time:3,subcategory:[{first: "sub2",time:4]}] }]
```

Array can go deeper and deeper. How can I calculate additional time? In my example I need result of "main" = 7

Is there a way to do foreach in foreach until end including calculate?

Answer (score 0):

First of you defined subcategory as [{first: string, time: number, subcategory: []}], but I think you instead meant to do {first: string, time: number, subcategory: []}[]. The first one is an array with the first element being defined, the second one is an array with all elements of the defined object type.

To get to your question: You can get an array of all object keys and values with Object.keys(o) and Object.values(o). Alternatively use Object.entries(o) to get an array of keyvalue-pairs.

Use this to create a recursive function adding up your times.